# Making a conditional loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm making a guessing game or computer science in school where the number to guess is seven. I have tried using while loops and if elif else statements but it doesn't seem to want to make a conditional loop My code is as follows:

```
guess=int(input("Guess a number!"))
var=1
while var==1:
    if guess !=7:
        print("Try again")
    else:
        print("Well done")
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks. I need it in about a week and a half's time.

Comment: Consider: where in your code do you ask the user for input? Does that allow the user to input data more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
guess=int(input("Guess a number!"))
var=1
while var==1:
    if guess !=7:
        print("Try again")
        guess=int(input("Guess a number!"))
    else:
        print("Well done")
        var=0 #set var to 0, to exit the loop
```

Try this. You need to exit the loop, and to do that, var needs to be set to 0.

Comment: I tried it, but with that, if I guess wrong then it just keeps printing "Try again" over and over.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the input again :). Try it now

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much this works! Appreciate your help and everyone else who helped!:D!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to allow your player to continuously guess the input needs to be at the top of the while loop, before the conditional-branch

```
while(True):
    guess = input("Make a guess: ")
    if(guess == 7):
        print(guess,"was correct!")
        break
    else:
        print("Nope. Guess again.")
```

Of course, you could make it more interesting in a variety of ways.